# Device not sending data to LWM2M Agent

Tags: iot, fiware, fiware-orion, lwm2m

I'm having trouble with LWM2M device sending data to the IOT Agent. The device connects to the server successfully.

However, it seems the device isn't sending data to the IOT Agent, with no helpful tip, sending the command:

```
curl --request POST \
   --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
   --header 'Fiware-Service: workshop' \
   --header 'Fiware-ServicePath: /' \
   --header 'X-Auth-Token: NULL' \
   --data 't|30' \
   -v \
     'http://localhost:4041/iot/d?k=workshop-devices&i=robot1'
```

It returns the message:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 4041 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 4041 (#0)
> POST /iot/d?k=workshop-devices&i=robot1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:4041
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: text/plain
> Fiware-Service: workshop
> Fiware-ServicePath: /
> X-Auth-Token: NULL
> Content-Length: 4
> 
* upload completely sent off: 4 out of 4 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Fiware-Correlator: 32da2092-8032-427a-86f2-19ae81a1ab47
< Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 145
< Date: Mon, 24 Sep 2018 10:30:25 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /iot/d</pre>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Not sure if anyone understands what's going here please.

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the steps of https://github.com/telefonicaid/lightweightm2m-iotagent/blob/master/docs/deviceProvisioning.md?

I ask this because using LWM2M, it is not possible to use curl commands to send observations from devices. You need to use an LWM2M client for that purpose.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for letting me know that curl commands cannot be used with LWM2M client. I have been following the steps you mention, but instead, trying to send update using curl.

Comment: @arilwan Did you achieve to follow successfully the steps of https://github.com/telefonicaid/lightweightm2m-iotagent/blob/master/docs/deviceProvisioning.md?